# How to determine the effective CSS properties of a WebElement in Selenium?

Tags: javascript, java, css, selenium, dom

I have the following HTML document (this is a simplified example):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    ...
</head>
<body style="background-color: blue;">
    <div id="myDiv" style="color: white;">HEY</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am loading this document into chromedriver and trying to determine an effective background colour of element `#myDiv`. Is there a way to do this in Selenium?

The obvious thing I tried:

```java
final WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#myDiv"));
System.out.println(elem.getCssValue("background-color"));
// Prints rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), expected rgb(0, 0, 255) or equivalent
```

I also tried running the following Javascript, but again, this only returns properties set on the element itself and ignores styles of parent elements:

```java
final WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#myDiv"));
final String computedStylePropertyScript = "return window.document.defaultView"
                 + ".getComputedStyle(arguments[0],null).getPropertyValue(arguments[1]);";
System.out.println((String) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(computedStylePropertyScript, elem, "background-color");
// Prints rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), expected rgb(0, 0, 255) or equivalent
```

Is there any way to read the effective value of the background (or foreground) colour the `WebElement` has in selenium?

Answer (score 2):

This will be more difficult.

The `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)` is correct. It means that the color is transparent and taken from the parent element.

The solution would be to than lookup the color of the parent.

Here is an example function to that.

```
private String getBGColor(WebElement elementToSearch) {
    WebElement current = elementToSearch;
    while(isTransparent(current.getCssValue("background-color"))) {
        if (current.getTagName().equals("body")) {
            return null;
        }
        // Find Parent
        current = current.findElement(By.xpath("./.."));
    }
    return current.getCssValue("background-color");
}

private boolean isTransparent(String color) {
    String colorMod = color.replaceAll("\\s+","").toLowerCase();
    return Arrays.asList("transparent","","rgba(0,0,0,0)").contains(colorMod);
}
```

Call it with

```
WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#myDiv"));
System.out.println(getBGColor(elem));
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I wanted to avoid DOM-based calculations, but you are making good point on transparency. I guess your solution will break down on absolutely positioned elements, but that is an imprecision I am OK with.